# eclipse cannot find userpreferences xml

Tags: android, preferences, android-resources

I'm writing an Android application and need to implement a settings `Activity`.

I've imported `android.R` as suggested in other posts which got rid of my first error.  But now I can't seem to resolve userpreferences using this code:

```
addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.userpreferences);
```

Eclipse can see R.xml but nothing past this, I'm thinking I might be missing something in the manifest that will make xml/userpreferences.xml visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using android.R I needed to import myappplication.R